# How to use Pandas to fetch specific rows?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandasql

I know pandas can fetch data from head or tail:

```
data = data.head(100)

data = data.tail(100)
```

what if I want to fetch the data from row 20th to row 30th:

any function like:

```
data =data.(from row 20th to row 30th)
```

Any friends can help?

Comment: `data[20:31]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice like normal list (and you have to use `31` to get with row `30`)

```
 df[20:31]
```

Or use `iloc` (`integer-location`)

```
 df.iloc[20:31]
```

Both use row numbers instead of indexes.

With `iloc` you can also select columns using numbers (first column has number `0`)

```
 df.iloc[20:31, 0]

 df.iloc[20:31, 0:1]
```

You can also use list of rows - ie. to get only 20th and 30th row.

```
 df.iloc[ [20,30] ]
```

and the same with columns

```
 df.iloc[ [20,30], [0,2] ]
```

and you can mix list with slice

```
 df.iloc[ 20:31, [0,2] ]

 df.iloc[ [20,30], 0:2 ]
```

In slicing you can use `start:end:step`

```
 df.iloc[ 20:31:2 ]
```

and `:` to get all rows when you want to select only columns

```
 df.iloc[ : , [0,2] ]
```

and `start:` and `:end`

```
 df.iloc[ 20: ]

 df.iloc[ :30 ]
```

and negative value to count from end

```
 df.iloc[ -2: ]
```

You can also use `slice()`

```
 df.iloc[ slice(20,31) ]

 s = slice(20,31)
 df.iloc[ s ]

 s = slice(20,31,2)
 df.iloc[ s ]
```

BTW: if you prefer indexes instead row numbers you can use `loc`

```
 df.loc[120:130]

 df.loc[ 120:130, ['A', 'C'] ]
```

---

Doc: [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). More: [User Guide - indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

---

Example code. I specially create indexes `100:140` so they are different then row numbers

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(40), 'B': range(10,50), 'C': range(-50, -10)}, index=range(100,140))

print('\n--- all ---\n')
print(df)

print('\n--- rows from 20 to 30 (all columns) ---\n')
print(df[20:31])

print('\n--- rows from 20 to 30 (all columns) ---\n')
print(df.iloc[20:31])

print('\n--- rows from 20 to 30 and column 0 ---\n')
print(df.iloc[20:31, 0])

print('\n--- rows 20,30 (all columns) ---\n')
print(df.iloc[[20,31]])

print('\n--- rows 20,30 and columns 0,2 ---\n')
print(df.iloc[[20,31], [0,2]])

print('\n--- rows from 20 to 30 and columns 0,2 ---\n')
print(df.iloc[ 20:31, [0,2]])

print('\n--- indexes 120 to 130 (all columns) ---\n')
print(df.loc[120:130])

print('\n--- indexes 120 to 130 and columns A,C ---\n')
print(df.loc[120:130, ['A','C']])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
data=data.iloc[20:31,:]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.